# Perspective Rotation about Y axis

Tags: perspectives

I have a 2D image and I want to create a anaglyph image for this single 2D image. To do this I need to create Left and Right views. I will considar my 2D image as Left view and I want to create Right View now.

I came to know that the perspective rotation (about Y axis) and perspective skews will give the right image.

I know that the perspective projection is related to 3D.

Basically I am new to 3D programming.

Can you plz explain how to do perspective rotation abuout Y-axis. And how can I apply this to my 2D image.I am using C++.

Thank you verymuch

N.A.Reddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an anaglyph from a 2D image.  You need either two 2D images that were taken slightly apart from each other or you need a 3D image.  You can try and generate 3D information from a 2D image but that's almost impossible and an active area of research.

Comment: Hi Pace,

Thank you very much for your information.

But perspective transilations will give a another image with slight movement of a give 2D and there by we can construct a 3D. 

Can any one please help, what is perspective rotation about Y axis and how to apply this to 2D image using C++.

Thank you verymuch

N.A.Reddy.

Comment: A perspective rotation does not rotate the contents of an image, but it actually rotates the image itself.  Imagine you are holding a photograph in front of you.  If you rotate the photograph slightly you won't change the contents of the photograph, merely the photograph itself.

Comment: If you want to try this out anyways you can generate a perspective projection from 4 point correspondences.  To generate a projection that rotates around the y axis you do the following: Take the top left and bottom left points and move them slightly to the right.  Take the top right and bottom right points and move them slightly left. (the amount you move left should equal the amount you move right).  This will give you 4 correspondences.  The further you move the points the greater the angle of rotation.